# Choosing variables for neural network used for image recognition

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, octave

I have a training set of 89 images of 6 different domino tiles plus one "control" group of a baby - all divided over 7 groups. The output y is thus 7. Each image is 100x100 and is black and white, resulting in an X of 100.000.

I am using the 1 hidden layer neural network-code from Andrew Ng's coursera course using Octave. It has been slightly modified.

I first tried this with 3 different groups (two domino tiles, one baby) and it managed to get a near 100% accuracy. I have now increased it to 7 different image groups. The accuracy has dropped WAY down and it is hardly getting anything right but the baby photos (which differ highly from the domino tiles).

I have tried 10 different lambda values, 10 different neuron numbers between 5-20  as well as trying different amount of iterations and plotted it against cost and accuracy in order to find the best fit.

I also tried feature normalization (commented out in the code below) but it didn't help.

This is the code I am using:

```
% Initialization
clear ; close all; clc; more off;
pkg load image;

fprintf('Running Domino Identifier ... \n');

%iteration_vector = [100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000, 30000];
%accuracies = [];
%costs = [];

%for iterations_i = 1:length(iteration_vector)

  # INPUTS
  input_layer_size  = 10000;  % 100x100 Input Images of Digits
  hidden_layer_size = 50;   % Hidden units
  num_labels = 7;          % Number of different outputs
  iterations = 100000; % Number of iterations during training
  lambda = 0.13;
  %hidden_layer_size = hidden_layers(hidden_layers_i);
  %lambda = lambdas(lambda_i)
  %iterations = %iteration_vector(iterations_i)

  [X,y] = loadTrainingData(num_labels);
  %[X_norm, mu, sigma] = featureNormalize(X_unnormed);
  %X = X_norm;

  initial_Theta1 = randInitializeWeights(input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size);
  initial_Theta2 = randInitializeWeights(hidden_layer_size, num_labels);
  initial_nn_params = [initial_Theta1(:) ; initial_Theta2(:)];

  [J grad] = nnCostFunction(initial_nn_params, input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size, num_labels, X, y, lambda);

  fprintf('\nTraining Neural Network... \n')

  %  After you have completed the assignment, change the MaxIter to a larger
  %  value to see how more training helps.
  options = optimset('MaxIter', iterations);

  % Create "short hand" for the cost function to be minimized
  costFunction = @(p) nnCostFunction(p, input_layer_size, hidden_layer_size, num_labels, X, y, lambda);

  % Now, costFunction is a function that takes in only one argument (the
  % neural network parameters)
  [nn_params, cost] = fmincg(costFunction, initial_nn_params, options);

  % Obtain Theta1 and Theta2 back from nn_params
  Theta1 = reshape(nn_params(1:hidden_layer_size * (input_layer_size + 1)), ...
                   hidden_layer_size, (input_layer_size + 1));

  Theta2 = reshape(nn_params((1 + (hidden_layer_size * (input_layer_size + 1))):end), ...
                   num_labels, (hidden_layer_size + 1));

  displayData(Theta1(:, 2:end));
  [predictionData, images] = loadTrainingData(num_labels);
  [h2_training, pred_training] = predict(Theta1, Theta2, predictionData);
  fprintf('\nTraining Accuracy: %f\n', mean(double(pred_training' == y)) * 100);

  %if length(accuracies) > 0
  %  accuracies = [accuracies; mean(double(pred_training' == y))];
  %else
  % accuracies = [mean(double(pred_training' == y))];
  %end

  %last_cost = cost(length(cost));
  %if length(costs) > 0
  %  costs = [costs; last_cost];
  %else
  % costs = [last_cost];
  %end
%endfor % Testing samples

fprintf('Loading prediction images');
[predictionData, images] = loadPredictionData();
[h2, pred] = predict(Theta1, Theta2, predictionData)

for i = 1:length(pred)  
  figure;
  displayData(predictionData(i, :));
  title (strcat(translateIndexToTile(pred(i)), " Certainty:", num2str(max(h2(i, :))*100))); 
  pause;
endfor
%y = provideAnswers(im_vector);
```

My questions are now:

1. Are my numbers "off" in terms of a great difference between X and the rest?
2. What should I do to improve this Neural Network?
3. If I do feature normalization, do I need to multiply the numbers back to the 0-255 range again somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I do to improve this Neural Network?

Use a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) with multiple layers (e.g., 5 layers). For vision problems, CNNs outperform MLPs by wide margins. Here, you are using an MLP with a single hidden layer. It is plausible that this network will not perform well on an image problem with 7 classes. One concern is the amount of training data that you have. Generally, we want at least hundreds of samples per class.

> If I do feature normalization, do I need to multiply the numbers back to the 0-255 range again somewhere?

Generally, not for classification. Normalization can be viewed as a preprocessing step. However, if you working on a problem like image reconstruction, then you would need to convert back to the original domain at the end.

Comment: Thanks, Brad! This example was used in the course for handwritten numbers but they were 20x20 px and had more examples. As it worked for my 3 classes I thought it would be fixable for 7 classes as well but I guess the 2x+ amount of classes does not mean the problem is 2x more difficult but far more. Is that correct? Like, if I would have 30 output (y) classes that would not make it 10x more difficult/computer heavy but a larger factor?

Comment: Glad to help! That is an interesting question - I do not have a clear answer. Generally, I expect that as more classes are added, we actually need to add fewer parameters for each additional class, as the learned features (especially at lower layers) can be used by many of the classes.  The current standard evaluation image dataset is ImageNet, which has 1000 classes and generally requires millions of network weights to achieve good performance.